# DefaultKeyBinding.dict - How to hold F1 key + press second key to trigger an action?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

i'd like to create some custom keyboard shortcuts with the help of DefaultKeyBinding.dict. This generally works fine, but i'd like to pimp it to the next level ... if that's possible:

This (simplified example) works:

```
"^x"  = (insertText:, "hello");
```

it translates to: hold ctrl, then press x --> "hello" is written. great :-)

Now i'd like to use the F1 key \UF704 as a modifier instead of ctrl:

```
"\UF704x"  = (insertText:, "hello");
```

Here, the F1 key does not wait for the x key to be pressed but is interpreted immediately. So what is actually is executed is a press on F1, and then "x" is written.

What I'd need is a modificator that says "hold F1 and wait for that second key, only then execute the commands.

(this is simplified, i'm actually working with F13-F16 and more complex things to execute, but it doesn't matter for the question.)